# Need to get some value of variable from linked lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have some page with form, which loading some data to POST when i submit it. Then it links user to the next page. On this page I catch data from POST, and I have two dropdownlists, where the second one depends on the first. The first get's value from POST data:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#markid").val("'.$GLOBALS["i"].'"); </script>';
```

Where $GLOBALS["i"] = id from DB, which has kept in data from POST by previous page.
But it doesn't work for the second dropdownlist which depends on it:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#comm").val("'.$GLOBALS["i1"].'"); </script>';
```

I think it can be from the part of code, which realises depending of the second dropdown list:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
var id = jQuery(".mark").val();
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type:"POST",
    url: "wp-content/com.php",
    data: {id_mark: id},
    success: function(data){
jQuery(".comm").html(data);
}
});
       jQuery(".mark").change(function(){
var id = jQuery(".mark").val();
if(id==0){
}
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "wp-content/com.php",
    data: {id_mark: id},
    success: function(data){
          jQuery(".comm").html(data);
}
});
});
```

Where "mark" - first dropdownlist, "comm" - the second one.
This is the first part of my problem.
The second: I have some value on the page which depends on the value of the second dropdownlist. I tried to:

```
jQuery(".comm").change(function(){
var id = jQuery(".comm").val();
if(id==0){
}
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "wp-content/pricecar.php",
    data: {id_mark: id},
    success: function(data){
          jQuery(".price9").html(data);
var price1 = jQuery(".price1").val();
var price2 = jQuery(".price2").val();
var price3 = jQuery(".price3").val();
var price4 = jQuery(".price4").val();
var price5 = jQuery(".price5").val();
var price6 = jQuery(".price6").val();
var price7 = jQuery(".price7").val();
var price8 = jQuery(".price8").val();
var price9 = jQuery(".price9").val();
jQuery.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "../wp-content/price.php",
            data: {price1: price1,price2: price2,price3: price3,price4: price4,price5: price5,price6: price6,price7: price7,price8: price8, price9: data},
            success: function(data){
                jQuery(".summPrice").html(data);
            }
});
                            }
           });
```

But it works only one time, and i don't know why.
I'll be glad for any offers.

Comment: Could you post the relevant html rendered by the php? And how are you filling up the dropdowns? Directly from the php or with another ajax call?

Comment: `<select class="mark" id="markid"><option value='0'></option>
<?php>global $wpdb;
$query= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM 'wp_mark' ");
$i2=0;
for($i2;$i2<count($query);$i2++){
echo "<option value='".$query[$i2]->id."'style="".">".$query[$i2]->mark."</option>";
}
</?>
</select>` and the second you've seen in code i posted below, look at: `jQuery(".mark").change(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full visibility of the rendered html and of the ajax responses, but I would give a try with:

Remove this lines

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#markid").val("'.$GLOBALS["i"].'"); 
</script>';

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#comm").val("'.$GLOBALS["i1"].'"); </script>';
```

And do something like this where you print the html

```
...
<select id="markid" data-val="<?php echo isset($GLOBALS["i"]) ? $GLOBALS["i"] : -1;?>"></select>
<select id="comm" data-val="<?php echo isset($GLOBALS["i1"]) ? $GLOBALS["i1"] : -1;?>"></select>
```

And in your javascript have something like

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    //when everything is ready
    $(fillUpCommOptions);
    $(watchSelectsChanges);

    function fillUpCommOptions() {
        var id = $('#markid').data('val') ? $('#markid').data('val') : $('#markid').val();
        $('#markid').removeAttr('data-val');//remove data-val, at next change event we want the select new val
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "wp-content/com.php",
            data: {id_mark: id},
            success: function (data) {
                //assuming data is something like
                // '<option value="niceValue">nice value</option>
                $("#comm").html(data);
                if ($("#comm").data('val')) {
                    //apply values from post also for the second dropdown
                    // assuming that data contains and option with value == $("#comm").data('val')
                    $("#comm").val($("#comm").data('val'));
                    $('#comm').removeAttr('data-val');

                    $("#comm").change()//trigger change after setting the value
                }

            }
        });
    }

    function watchSelectsChanges() {
        $('#markid')
            .off('change')//just in case, could not be needed
            .on('change', fillUpCommOptions);

        $('#comm')
            .off('change')//just in case, could not be needed
            .on('change', handleDependentValues);
    }

    function handleDependentValues() {
        var id = $("#comm").val();
        if (id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "wp-content/pricecar.php",
                data: {id_mark: id},
                success: function (data) {
                    jQuery(".price9").html(data);
                    var price1 = jQuery(".price1").val();
                    var price2 = jQuery(".price2").val();
                    var price3 = jQuery(".price3").val();
                    var price4 = jQuery(".price4").val();
                    var price5 = jQuery(".price5").val();
                    var price6 = jQuery(".price6").val();
                    var price7 = jQuery(".price7").val();
                    var price8 = jQuery(".price8").val();
                    var price9 = jQuery(".price9").val();
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../wp-content/price.php",
                        data: {
                            price1: price1,
                            price2: price2,
                            price3: price3,
                            price4: price4,
                            price5: price5,
                            price6: price6,
                            price7: price7,
                            price8: price8,
                            price9: data
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            jQuery(".summPrice").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```